# Is it possible to autosize or autogrow for input text and textarea using CSS only?

Tags: css, xhtml

[James Padolsey's](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/) and [ahaxe's](http://jsbin.com/ahaxe) jquery scripts are two very good instances on autogrowing form fields.

Likewise, autosize can be accomplished in a number of ways using Javascript.

But, just wondering, is there anyway to do any kind of autosize or autogrow with CSS only? I don't know CSS deep enough, so you know, with all those pseudo-classes and CSS3, I'd guess this might be possible.

Or maybe the only option would be using either `<input size>` or `style="width: em;"`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [contenteditable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) attribute on an element and then customize it as you like [in the css](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable):

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, what time can't do? I wonder when this was actually implemented.

Comment: Warning: `contenteditable` is not a replacement for native input fields

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. Really. It can only be done using JavaScript.

Comment: I'll wait a couple days hoping for someone to beg different! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a div-element to contentEditable. It will behave the same way as the textarea, but the benefit is that you only need to use CSS instead of various plugins.

```
$(<selector>).attr(contentEditable, 'true');
```

In CSS you  set m`in-height`, `max-height`, even `-webkit-transition` property works for animation I think. Don't forget to set `word-wrap` property to `break-word`, so the words remains in the element.

Comment: I don't get it. You provided a jQuery snippet there. That's javascript. The point on using CSS only is exactly to avoid using client side scripts.

Comment: that jqeury snippet is there because you need to set it to contenteditbale, which means that you can input some text. Otherwise, it will behave like an ordinary div. Than you can manipulate it with CSS like an ordinary div.

Comment: And if you would like to get the value of it. instead of typing `.value` in javascript type `.innerHTML`. As you might already know;)

Comment: One big benefit: Some of the Jquery plugins actually calculates text length, not 100% sure about this though. What I have tested the autogrowing is uneven for some plugin. A contentEditbale Div behaves like an ordinary div when it comes to text overflow. You define how it is going to behave in CSS yourself and there is no uneven autogrowing

Comment: Dude, still missing the point. I had a page I wanted to build without javascript and for everything else I was able to handle without it, using only CSS and HTML. This was a critical point to keep not using javascript. I don't really have any good reason to not use it, but I bet there might be other reason than making the page lighter. CSS3 does take the role of many old javascripts on the layout, so I just figured it might be able to do that too. Anyways, I think I'm complicating the point to you rather than making it clear: **this questions is about *NO* javascript**. :D

Comment: @SzymonWygnański you should put your comment as a separate answer, and the OP should mark it as correct, since this is exactly what the OP asked for in his question.

Comment: @epegzz thanks. I would never know about his comment, as I didn't get notified about it.